# Visual Studio 2015 Android debugging click event causes debugger to stop

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-virtual-device

When I set an event for a button in my code and set a breakpoint on it, debugger stopped.
Note that I don't have any problem with breakpoint and debugger in other cases, and I'm using AVD virtual device.

Comment: you mean that debugging stopped and vs exited from debugging mode? was the app still running though?

Comment: @Alex : yes exactly

Comment: I would recommend to configure your debugger to break at every exception. i suppose there is one that your debugger doesn't stop at